# NuGet: nuget pack does not include files

Tags: nuget

I'm trying to create a NuGet package with the following command:

```
nuget.exe pack MyBeautiful.nuspec
```

Which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package>
    <metadata>
        ...
    </metadata>
    <files>
        <file src="\MyBeautifulApp\bin\Release\*" target="." />
    </files>
</package>
```

With version 3.4.4 of NuGet the generated packaged is 3.8 MB in size but none of my files are included. The NuGet package is empty.

If I try exactly the same with an earlier version of NuGet (3.3.0) my files are included correctly.

Is this a known bug in NuGet 3.4.4 or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. This line in the nuspec file:

```
<file src="\MyBeautifulApp\bin\Release\*" target="." />
```

Should be:

```
<file src="\MyBeautifulApp\bin\Release\*" target="" />
```

So no dot in the target.